# Return total months in overlapping date range for each ID in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, date-range

Sample data:

| MBR_ID | MIN_SPANFROM | MAX_SPANFROM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202101 | 202105 |
| 1 | 202101 | 202108 |
| 1 | 202111 | 202112 |
| 2 | 202101 | 202109 |
| 2 | 202103 | 202108 |
| 2 | 202110 | 202110 |
| 3 | 202102 | 202107 |
| 3 | 202104 | 202110 |
| 3 | 202109 | 202112 |
| 4 | 202101 | 202105 |
| 4 | 202101 | 202105 |
| 5 | 202109 | 202110 |
| 5 | 202105 | 202106 |

date format: yyyymm

Required output:

| MBR_ID | TOTAL_MONTHS_2021 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 |

Example:

For ID `1`, date range: `Jan to may`, `Jan to Aug` and `Nov to Dec` then total months is `Jan to Aug + Nov to Dec = 8 + 2 = 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
WITH as_dates (mbr_id, min_spanfrom, max_spanfrom) AS (
  SELECT mbr_id,
         TO_DATE(min_spanfrom, 'YYYYMM'),
         TO_DATE(max_spanfrom, 'YYYYMM')
  FROM   table_name
),
group_changes (mbr_id, min_spanfrom, max_spanfrom, group_change) AS (
  SELECT d.*,
         CASE
         WHEN min_spanfrom
              <= MAX(max_spanfrom) OVER (
                   PARTITION BY mbr_id
                   ORDER BY min_spanfrom, max_spanfrom DESC
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                 )
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END
  FROM   as_dates d
),
groups (mbr_id, min_spanfrom, max_spanfrom, grp) AS (
  SELECT mbr_id,
         min_spanfrom,
         max_spanfrom,
         SUM(group_change) OVER (
           PARTITION BY mbr_id
           ORDER BY min_spanfrom, max_spanfrom DESC
         )
  FROM   group_changes
),
months (mbr_id, months) AS (
  SELECT mbr_id,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(MAX(max_spanfrom), MIN(min_spanfrom)) + 1
  FROM   groups
  GROUP BY mbr_id, grp
)
SELECT mbr_id,
       SUM(months) AS total_months
FROM   months
GROUP BY mbr_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (MBR_ID, MIN_SPANFROM, MAX_SPANFROM) AS
SELECT 1, 202101, 202105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 202101, 202108 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 202111, 202112 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 202101, 202109 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 202103, 202108 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 202110, 202110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 202102, 202107 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 202104, 202110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 202109, 202112 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 202101, 202105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 202101, 202105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 202109, 202110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 202105, 202106 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MBR_ID | TOTAL_MONTHS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 |
> | 2 | 10 |
> | 3 | 11 |
> | 4 | 5 |
> | 5 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a031cd7e73f91691c1dce1127e92ad55)*